# Retrieve folder contents from Windchill API

Tags: ptc-windchill

We want to use the Windchill API for integrating Windchill into our application.
I know how to get the folder structure, but I don't know how to get folder contents.

I would like to get the list of documents by supplying the folder as parameter. I was looking at the documentation but I cannot seem to find anything useful.

This is the method for retrieving folders

```
get /v1/folders/{id}/folders
```

This is our Windchill structure and on the right I need the document list.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP6cX.png)

Any help is appreciated.